# Parsoid doesn't start

Tags: parsoid

I installed parsoid from its official repository, and configured it correctly by adding my Mediawiki API to `/etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js`. I also removed the Interwiki options from my `/usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/localsettings.js`file, because they seem to be replaced by the parsoidConfig.setMwApi option in the settings.js file.

When running `nodejs /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js` from the command promt, I get the following error message:

```
[fatal][worker][4915] uncaught exception object is not a function
TypeError: object is not a function
    at new ParsoidService (/usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/ParsoidService.js:43:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js:203:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
[warning][master][4882] worker 4911 died (1), restarting.
```

When I run `service parsoid start` and `service parsoid status` I am always getting the information, that there is no parsoid process running.

Can someone explain me why Parsoid does not work?

EDIT:

localsettings.js

```
/*
 * This is a sample configuration file.
 *
 * Copy this file to localsettings.js and edit that file to fit your needs.
 *
 * Also see the file ParserService.js for more information.
 */

exports.setup = function( parsoidConfig ) {
    // The URL here is supposed to be your MediaWiki installation root
    //parsoidConfig.setInterwiki( 'localhost', 'http://domain.com/Wiki/api.php' );
    //parsoidConfig.setInterwiki( 'foo', 'http://localhost/wikiarst/api.php' );
    //parsoidConfig.setInterwiki( 'noconn', 'http://213.127.84.12:80/wikiarst/api.php' );
    //parsoidConfig.setInterwiki( 'disney', 'http://disneychannel.wikia.com/api.php' );

    // Use the PHP preprocessor to expand templates via the MW API (default true)
    //parsoidConfig.usePHPPreProcessor = true;

    // Use selective serialization (default false)
    parsoidConfig.useSelser = true;

    // parsoid cache url
    //parsoidConfig.parsoidCacheURI = 'http://localhost:8000/';

    //parsoidConfig.trace = true;
    //parsoidConfig.traceFlags = 'selser,wts';
    //parsoidConfig.traceFlags = 'selser';

    //parsoidConfig.defaultAPIProxyURI = 'http://localhost/';

};


/* vim: set filetype=javascript noexpandtab ts=4 sw=4 cindent : */
```

settings.js

```
/*
 * This is a sample configuration file.
 *
 * Copy this file to localsettings.js and edit that file to fit your needs.
 *
 * Also see:
 * - api/server.js for more information about passing config files via
 *   the commandline.
 * - lib/mediawiki.ParsoidConfig.js all the properties
 *   that you can configure here. Not all properties are
 *   documented here.
 */
'use strict';

exports.setup = function(parsoidConfig) {
    // Set your own user-agent string
    // Otherwise, defaults to "Parsoid/<current-version-defined-in-package.json>"
    //parsoidConfig.userAgent = "My-User-Agent-String";

    // The URL of your MediaWiki API endpoint.
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi({ prefix: 'localhost', uri: 'http://domain.com/Wiki/api.php' });
    // To specify a proxy (or proxy headers) specific to this prefix (which
    // overrides defaultAPIProxyURI) use:
    /*
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi({
        prefix: 'localhost',
        uri: 'http://localhost/w/api.php',
        // set `proxy` to `null` to override and force no proxying.
        proxy: {
            uri: 'http://my.proxy:1234/',
            headers: { 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https' } // headers are optional
        }
    });
    */

    // We pre-define wikipedias as 'enwiki', 'dewiki' etc. Similarly
    // for other projects: 'enwiktionary', 'enwikiquote', 'enwikibooks',
    // 'enwikivoyage' etc. (default true)
    //parsoidConfig.loadWMF = false;

    // A default proxy to connect to the API endpoints.
    // Default: undefined (no proxying).
    // Overridden by per-wiki proxy config in setMwApi.
    //parsoidConfig.defaultAPIProxyURI = 'http://proxy.example.org:8080';

    // Enable debug mode (prints extra debugging messages)
    //parsoidConfig.debug = true;

    // Use the PHP preprocessor to expand templates via the MW API (default true)
    //parsoidConfig.usePHPPreProcessor = false;

    // Use selective serialization (default false)
    parsoidConfig.useSelser = true;

    // Allow cross-domain requests to the API (default '*')
    // Sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
    // disable:
    //parsoidConfig.allowCORS = false;
    // restrict:
    //parsoidConfig.allowCORS = 'some.domain.org';

    // Set to true for using the default performance metrics reporting to statsd
    // If true, provide the statsd host/port values
    /*
    parsoidConfig.useDefaultPerformanceTimer = true;
    parsoidConfig.txstatsdHost = 'statsd.domain.org';
    parsoidConfig.txstatsdPort = 8125;
    */

    // Alternatively, define performanceTimer as follows:
    /*
    parsoidConfig.performanceTimer = {
        timing: function(metricName, time) { }, // do-something-with-it
        count: function(metricName, value) { }, // do-something-with-it
    };
    */

    // How often should we emit a heap sample? Time in ms.
    // This setting is only relevant if you have enabled
    // performance monitoring either via the default metrics
    // OR by defining your own performanceTimer properties
    //parsoidConfig.heapUsageSampleInterval = 5 * 60 * 1000;

    // Allow override of port/interface:
    //parsoidConfig.serverPort = 8000;
    //parsoidConfig.serverInterface = '127.0.0.1';

    // The URL of your LintBridge API endpoint
    //parsoidConfig.linterAPI = 'http://lintbridge.wmflabs.org/add';

    // Require SSL certificates to be valid (default true)
    // Set to false when using self-signed SSL certificates
    //parsoidConfig.strictSSL = false;

    // Use a different server for CSS style modules.
    // Set to true to use bits.wikimedia.org, or to a string with the URI.
    // Leaving it undefined (the default) will use the same URI as the MW API,
    // changing api.php for load.php.
    //parsoidConfig.modulesLoadURI = true;

    // Suppress some warnings from the Mediawiki API
    // (defaults to suppressing warnings which the Parsoid team knows to
    // be harmless)
    //parsoidConfig.suppressMwApiWarnings = /annoying warning|other warning/;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `/etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js` and or `/usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/localsettings.js` is broken, and Parsoid is crashing as soon as it tries to look at your `parsoidConfig`.  I recommend going through the instructions at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/Setup#Configuration carefully, and if you still have problems then please post excerpts of your settings files.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I did the setup exactly like it was explained in the guide and edited both files, so that they are pointing to my MW API.

Comment: Ok, it looks like your Parsoid is crashing on the following line: `var app = express();` which is coming from `var express = require('express');` at the top of the file.  The parsoid package is bundled with the appropriate version of express, but perhaps you have a conflicting one installed?  What does `dpkg -l '*express*'` say?

Comment: Output: "dpkg-query: no packages found matching *express*"
Maybe it wasn't installed? I also took a look into the deb file, but there doesn't seem to be a application like express..

Comment: (This is assuming you're using version `0.4.1all` of the Parsoid package.)

Comment: Yes this is the version I am using. Now I ran "npm test" in the /usr/lib/parsoid directory, and I get multiple error messages like: "Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/parsoid/lib/mediawiki.tokenizer.peg.js'" or "This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"" ..